# I get error "unmatched '}'" when I scrape website(korter.az)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-re

I want to crawl all advertisements but output is "unmatched '}'". Is there any easy way to do it? I tried Beautifulsoup before but I think It's not correct way to do it or I'm using it wrong way.

How can I scrape all '199 yeni tikili binalar' from the website.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
url = "https://korter.az/yasayis-kompleksleri-baku"
html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r'2804\.jpg"\}\}\}\],(".*")', html_doc).group(1)
data = json.loads(literal_eval(data))


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel('korter.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: what items are you trying to get?

Comment: I want to get url and then all details about the 199  yeni tikili binalar. All inside urls. Can I get without get url I don't know. @Andrew Ryan

Comment: You're probably going to need to use something like Selenium for this as there seems to be a lot of Javascript to contend with. You'll also need to figure out how to handle paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site has an api which can be accessed by request

Url of the API is : "https://korter.az/api/building/listing?mainGeoObjectId=1&page=1&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ"

**Full Code**

```
import requests
import math
import pandas as pd


def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 20.0)) * 20


# Gettig no of results
url1 = f"https://korter.az/api/building/listing?mainGeoObjectId=1&page=1&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ"
r = requests.get(url1)
no_of_outcomes = r.json()["totalBuildingsCount"]
# since the data is 199 i am rounding up to 20 since i will divide no of outcomes by 20 as the api only provides with 20 results at a time
no_of_outcomes = roundup(no_of_outcomes)

# Getting Sub Url from each Page by looping.

result_url = []
previous_subdata = []

for k in range(1, int(no_of_outcomes/20)+1):
    url = f"https://korter.az/api/building/listing?mainGeoObjectId=1&page={k}&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ"
    r = requests.get(url)
    subdata = r.json()["buildings"]
    for i in subdata:
        suburl = "https://korter.az"+i["url"]
        result_url.append(suburl)


print(len(result_url))
df = pd.DataFrame(result_url)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
199
                                                0
0              https://korter.az/toca-residence-baki
1            https://korter.az/malibu-residence-baki
2                  https://korter.az/zirve-park-baki
3                https://korter.az/melissa-park-baki
4                 https://korter.az/white-hotel-baki
..                                               ...
194          https://korter.az/yasham-boulevard-baki
195                   https://korter.az/koroglu-baki
196              https://korter.az/luxor-palace-baki
197  https://korter.az/shirvanshahlar-residence-baki
198              https://korter.az/baki-baglari-baki

[199 rows x 1 columns]
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: it gave all urls I  want to grab all details which are inside of urls. How can I do that ? I want to get all details about all residences from site.

Comment: what all details do you need

Comment: 'X X mənzil layihələndirmələri və qiymətlər', 'X X xəri̇tədə Bakı' , 'Yaşayış kompleksinin xüsusiyyətləri', 'Ev haqqında məlumat', 
Mənzillər və qiymətlər
Xəri̇tədə
Tikinti gidişatı
Almaq yollari
Xüsusi̇yyətlər
Kompleks haqqinda
All these things actually I think there must be easy way to do it. I want to crawl all datas to excel.@louis joseph

Comment: add the sample excel file for reference

Comment: Resdience_name,m2_qiyməti,Construction_company(Tikinti şirkəti),Adress(Ünvan),1room,1roomarea,1unitprice,1roomprice,2room,2roomarea,2unitprice,2roomprice,3room,3roomarea,3unitprice,3roomprice,4room,4roomarea,4unitprice,4roomprice,5room,5roomarea,5unitprice,5roomprice,Latitude,Longitude,Construction_situation(Tikintinin vəziyyəti),Floor_count(Mərtəbələrin sayı),Texnoloji_quruluş,Bağlı_ərazilər,Divarlar,İstiliksistemi,İnfrastruktur,Kommunal,Korpusların_sayı,Lift,Parklanma,Xarici_fasad,Təmiri,Mənzil_sahəsi,Mənzillərin_sayı,Tavankların_hündürlüyü,Yataq_otaqları,Description

Comment: Residence_name:Toca Residence

Comment: 1room,1roomarea,1unitprice,1roomprice every is none because there is not 1 room.

Comment: 2room:True,  2roomarea:118,9-146,6,   2unitprice:2000,    2roomprice: 166000,   Address:Süleyman Vəzirov küç., 1/3

Comment: Construction_situation(Tikintinin vəziyyəti),Floor_count(Mərtəbələrin sayı),Texnoloji_quruluş,Bağlı_ərazilər,Divarlar,İstiliksistemi,İnfrastruktur,Kommunal,Korpusların_sayı,Lift,Parklanma,Xarici_fasad,Təmiri,Mənzil_sahəsi,Mənzillərin_sayı,Tavankların_hündürlüyü,Yataq_otaqları, These all are inside of 'Ev haqqında'.

Comment: i think it will be better if you add the screenshot of desired excel  headers in you question so that to will be easy to visualize

Comment: How can you find url which is inside of your code. Could you explain how can I find the respected api url for scraping jsons

Comment: you have to inspect the page and go to the network tab to find the HTTP requests made by the site.

Comment: I did that and look the Fetch/XHR but I couldn't see the url which u wrote. How did you find It actually I search for full data json in this site but just find infos about viewed building not all buildings. If you help me finding that it would be great. Also I see in some json files there are latitude and longitude but in others not. I cannot find full json.

Comment: they had changed the url to this `https://korter.az/pyapi/building/listing?mainGeoObjectId=1&page=3&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ` and this only appears in XHR only when next page button is clicked as the site when initiated first doesn't get data using HTTP json request but by using HTML injection.

Comment: I saw this url but it's not I want for example in this [url](https://korter.az/pyapi/autocomplete/viewed-buildings?buildingIds=[460,555,357,879,620,400,790]&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ) there are also geographical attributes but it's only datas which I viewed before . I do not know how can I find this or crawl for all products

Comment: `https://korter.az/pyapi/autocomplete/viewed-buildings?buildingIds=[353]&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ` the data you need is available in this URL. From the original code I posted, along with the URL get the "buildingId" from the json and pass it in the array for the `buildingids` this will give you the required output.

Comment: Please ask as a new question from now on since then only more people can find your question or query quicker and thus provide you with answer much quicker and optimized ways to achieve your result. since in comments only few people are notified about your new query

Comment: I cannot post new question because ban.

Comment: https://korter.az/pyapi/autocomplete/viewed-buildings?buildingIds=[353]&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ in this url there is just one product

Comment: you have to replace the array ie. buildingIds=[353] with all the building id from the json so in your case the URL you initially provided had [460,555,357,879,620,400,790] as the building ids just add a script to add these buildingid to the `https://korter.az/pyapi/autocomplete/viewed-buildings?buildingIds=[353]&lang=az-AZ&locale=az-AZ`